# Invalid procedure call or argument in vbscript

Tags: asp-classic

I am using vb script to upload a file to the server. The problem I'm having is that when I set the file to ASCII format like this...

```
Set oFile = oFS.CreateTextFile(sPath & FileName, True, False)
```

I get an error when the sub is called that says

> Invalid procedure call or argument

but if I set the file to unicode

```
Set oFile = oFS.CreateTextFile(sPath & FileName, True, True)
```

it uploads successfully but will not open because of the incorrect encoding.
The line that produces the error is this one if format is ASCII is this one

```
oFile.Write BinaryToString(FileData)
```

where `oFile` is the ASCII file I had created above

Here is the source code that produces the error. It's an upload function I got off the net..

```
Public Sub SaveToDisk(sPath)
        Dim oFS, oFile
        Dim nIndex

        If sPath = "" Or FileName = "" Then Exit Sub
        If Mid(sPath, Len(sPath)) <> "\" Then sPath = sPath & "\"

        Set oFS = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        If Not oFS.FolderExists(sPath) Then Exit Sub

        Set oFile = oFS.CreateTextFile(sPath & FileName, True, False)
        oFile.Write BinaryToString(FileData)

        oFile.Close
    End Sub

    Function BinaryToString(Binary)
        'Antonin Foller, http://www.motobit.com
        'Optimized version of a simple BinaryToString algorithm.

        Dim cl1, cl2, cl3, pl1, pl2, pl3
        Dim L
        cl1 = 1
        cl2 = 1
        cl3 = 1
        L = LenB(Binary)

        Do While cl1<=L
            pl3 = pl3 & Chr(AscB(MidB(Binary,cl1,1)))
            cl1 = cl1 + 1
            cl3 = cl3 + 1
            If cl3>300 Then
                pl2 = pl2 & pl3
                pl3 = ""
                cl3 = 1
                cl2 = cl2 + 1
                If cl2>200 Then
                    pl1 = pl1 & pl2
                    pl2 = ""
                    cl2 = 1
                End If
            End If
        Loop
        BinaryToString = pl1 & pl2 & pl3
    End Function
```

Could it be configurations on the server? If this makes any sense please help..

Comment: What data type is held in FileData and how is it acquired in the first place?

Answer (score 2):

I suspect BinaryToString returns not only ASCII (actually the current OEM codepage) characters but also other characters in the unicode range that are outside the OEM codepage set.

What exactly does BinaryToString do?

Comment: Function BinaryToString(Binary)
  'Antonin Foller, http://www.motobit.com
  'Optimized version of a simple BinaryToString algorithm.
  
  Dim cl1, cl2, cl3, pl1, pl2, pl3
  Dim L
  cl1 = 1
  cl2 = 1
  cl3 = 1
  L = LenB(Binary)
  
  Do While cl1<=L
   pl3 = pl3 & Chr(AscB(MidB(Binary,cl1,1)))
   cl1 = cl1 + 1
   cl3 = cl3 + 1
   If cl3>300 Then
    pl2 = pl2 & pl3
    pl3 = ""
    cl3 = 1
    cl2 = cl2 + 1
    If cl2>200 Then
     pl1 = pl1 & pl2
     pl2 = ""
     cl2 = 1
    End If
   End If
  Loop
  BinaryToString = pl1 & pl2 & pl3
 End Function

Comment: BinaryToString does return ASCII. The problem is that when I try to create the file in ASCII format, it gives me an error...
See the algorythm above

Answer (score -1):

After an unreasonably long time dealing with this same issue, without really making sense to me, and not related to Unicode, I finally got it to work with:

```
Set oFile = oFS.CreateTextFile(sPath & FileName, 8)
```

This page was useful to me:
http://ns7.webmasters.com/caspdoc/html/vbscript_filesystemobject_object_opentextfile_method.htm

Ilya Evdokimov