# Invalid procedure call or argument in vbscript AscB

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

The following code is used to save an image via an upload form.
It used to work perfectly, till a recently server move.

```
sValue = UploadRequest.Item("files").Item("Value")

sFullFilePath = sDestinationPath & sFileName

'Create FileSytemObject Component
Set oFSO = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

'Create and Write to a File
sPathEnd = Len(Server.mappath(Request.ServerVariables("PATH_INFO")))-14

Set oFile = oFSO.CreateTextFile(sFullFilePath, 8)

For i = 1 to LenB(sValue)

   oFile.Write chr(AscB(MidB(sValue,i,1)))   ' THIS IS THE ERROR LINE
Next

oFile.Close

Set oFile = Nothing
Set oFSO = Nothing
```

The error I am getting is: `Invalid procedure call or argument`

I have seen [Invalid procedure call or argument in vbscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1062670/invalid-procedure-call-or-argument-in-vbscript) but that does not seem to solve the issue.

ADDED: As explained, i saw the related question but the solution there does not work!

Any ideas?

Comment: Probably some issue with an encoding. You could try to check `sValue` and see if it has something unusual.

Comment: That script would only work if the form was uploaded and processed using an ASCII character set, if the server is defaulting to UTF-8 as newer versions of IIS do that will explain the invalid argument passed into `AscB()`.

Comment: @montonero yes it will be an encoding issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Invalid procedure call or argument in vbscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1062670/invalid-procedure-call-or-argument-in-vbscript). This is the exact same issue and the same advice is being given.

Comment: Thanks @Lankymart. Indeed, as i posted, i saw that answer, but the solution posted by Ilya did not seem to work for me.

Comment: @kneidels you are going to get the same advice here because the encoding is the issue, it's that simple. "Does not work" is not a good enough reason to raise a duplicate question as the duplicate question answers state AscB() is receiving characters that are not part of the ASCII character set. So you need to look at the encoding you are using when posting and what encoding you are processing with when retrieving the response. There are already plenty of questions/answers about Classic ASP encoding and encoding mismatches already on [so] go have a look.